# Global variable in namespace - Values differ in threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

Consider the following szenario:

- 2 different network-ports via `boost::asio` each in its own thread
- 1 port is receiving and processing data - `class DataConnection` wrapped in a `std::thread`
- 1 port is for sending statistics `class StatConnection` also wrapped in a `std::thread`

For counting connections (and other small data pieces) my idea was to use a `static` variable inside a `namespace` like:

```
#include <atomic>

namespace app {
 namespace status {
   static std::atomic<long> counter = 0; 
 }
}
```

This works fine for the `DataConnection` class. Here I increment `counter` in the c'tor and see the value increments.

But `counter` in my `StatConnection` class is always `0`

Why can this happen?

I've tried some alternatives:

- exchanging `std::atomic<long>` for `static volatile long`:  Did not made a difference.
- using the namespace without `static` keyword.

Then I got linker errors:

```
multiple definition of `app::status::searchtime'
./src/status/Status.o:/[...]/include/status/Status.hpp:16: first defined here
[...]
```

So why is the value of `count` different between threads?

Comment: Huh? Static member of namespace? Why not just static member of class?

Comment: The Class only exists for a short time and the boost::asio related classes are started n-times via std::thread. So I thought putting it into a namespace makes this seperate. But a static member could solve the Problem I'll look into it. I'm still not sure why the namespace approach didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`static` in namespace scope introduces internal linkage, so each translation unit will have its own copy of `counter` – quite the opposite of what you actually want!

Use `extern` instead, in the header:

```
//foo.h:
#include <atomic>

namespace app {
    namespace status {
        extern std::atomic<long> counter;
    }
}
```

Then define the variable in **one** translation unit:

```
//foo.cpp:
#include "foo.h"

namespace app {
    namespace status {
        std::atomic<long> counter{0L};
    }
}
```

Comment: to get it working with `std::atomic<long>` I had to write in `foo.cpp`: `std::atomic<long> counter(0);`

Comment: @emteh : Ah, I didn't know whether the constructor was explicit or not. I'll edit, thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what the "extern" keyword mean in this context?

Comment: @JonaFane : In this context it is a [storage class specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), and is necessary there in order to make `app::status::counter` in the header a _declaration_ rather than [a _definition_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).